# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query_num_rows() in

Tags: php

Soy bastante novato y no se porque me sale lo siguiente

> ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query_num_rows() in C:\wamp\www\Curso-PHP\Seccion4\2 PHP y MYSQL\2\login.php on line 21
>
> ( ! ) Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query_num_rows() in C:\wamp\www\Curso-PHP\Seccion4\2 PHP y MYSQL\2\login.php on line 21

Acá dejo el código:

```
<?php

//iniciar la sesion y la conexion a db 
require_once 'includes/conexion.php';

//recoger datos del formularios
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //Borrar error antiguo
    if (isset($_SESSION['error_login'])) {
        # code...
        session_unset($_SESSION['error_login']);
    }

    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    
    //comprobar las credenciales del usuario
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE email = '$email' ";
    $login =mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if ($login && mysql_query_num_rows($login) ==1) {
        # code...
        $usuario =mysql_fetch_assoc($login);

    }
    //comprobar password / cifrar
    $verify = password_verify($password, $usuario['password']);
    
    if ($verify) {
        //utilizar una sesion para guardar los datos del usuario
        $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;


    }else {
        //si algo falla enviar una sesion con el fallo
        $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Login incorrecto";
    }

}else {
    # code...
    $_SESSION['error_login'] = "Login incorrecto";
}

//redirigir al index.php
header('Location: Index.php');
```

Comment: Estás usando la extensión `mysql` que está obsoleta para obtener el numero de registros. Debes usar `mysqli`. Aquí encuentras la documentación oficial: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es exactamente lo que dice el mensaje, la función `mysql_query_num_rows` no esta definida, ya que no existe.

### Solución:

Para obtener la cantidad de registros obtenidos por la consulta podrías usar [`mysqli_num_rows($login)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Es decir:

```
$login =mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if ($login && mysqli_num_rows($login)==1) {
    # code...
```

---

**Observación:**

Puedo ver que estas mesclando funciones de `mysql` con las de [`mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (*notese la `i` al final*), por ejemplo, en lugar de usar `mysql_fetch_assoc` deberías usar [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: Gracias por la observacion, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error despues de cambiar los detalles que me dijiste

Comment: Aportando, tambien revisa en tu archivo conexion.php que la conexion igualmente la hagas con mysqli